# Scala-Spark: Cannot use UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am having an issue using UDF in Spark (Scala). This is a sample code:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}

val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test") 
             .master("local[*]")
             .getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

def func(a: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = a
val funcUDF = udf((a: Array[Int]) => func(a))

var data = Seq(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(3, 4, 5), Array(6, 2, 4)).toDF("items")
data = data.withColumn("a", funcUDF(col("items")))
data.show()
```

The error I get is related to a ClassCastException, saying that it is impossible to cast from `scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef` to `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.$anonfun$f$2`. I add a part of the stack below. If it can help, I am using https://community.cloud.databricks.com/.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
> scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [I  at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.$anonfun$f$2(ScalaUDF.scala:155)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.eval(ScalaUDF.scala:1125)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias.eval(namedExpressions.scala:156)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedMutableProjection.apply(InterpretedMutableProjection.scala:83)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$$anonfun$apply$15.$anonfun$applyOrElse$70(Optimizer.scala:1557)
> at
> scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
> at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)  at
> scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)   at
> scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)  at
> scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:298)   at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$$anonfun$apply$15.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:1557)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$$anonfun$apply$15.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:1552)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$1(TreeNode.scala:322)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:80)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:322)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:153)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:151)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:327)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:412)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:250)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:410)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:363)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:327)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:153)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:151)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:327)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:412)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:250)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:410)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:363)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:327)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:153)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:151)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:327)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:412)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:250)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:410)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:363)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:327)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:153)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:151)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:311)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$.apply(Optimizer.scala:1552)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$.apply(Optimizer.scala:1551)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:152)
> at
> scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:60)
> at
> scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:68)
> at
> scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foldLeft(WrappedArray.scala:38)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:149)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:141)
> at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)  at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:141)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:119)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:88)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:119)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$optimizedPlan$1(QueryExecution.scala:107)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:171)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:836)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:171)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:104)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:104)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$writePlans$4(QueryExecution.scala:246)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$.append(QueryPlan.scala:466)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$QueryExecution$$writePlans(QueryExecution.scala:246)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toString(QueryExecution.scala:256)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:109)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:249)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:101)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:836)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:77)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:199)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3700)  at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2711)     at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2918)     at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:305)   at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:342)    at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:838)  at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:797)  at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:806)  at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:14)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:164)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:166)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:168)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:170)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:172)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:174)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:176)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:178)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:180)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:182)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:184)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:186)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:188)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:190)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:192)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:194)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:196)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:198)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:200)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:202)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:204)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:206)    at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:208)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:210)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:212)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:214)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$$iw.(command-1114467142343660:216)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read.(command-1114467142343660:218)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$.(command-1114467142343660:222)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$read$.(command-1114467142343660)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(:7)
> at
> lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$eval$.$print(:6)
> at lineedcf33d032244134ad784ac9de826d3b265.$eval.$print()
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:745)
> at
> scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1021)
> at
> scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$interpret$1(IMain.scala:574)
> at
> scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:41)
> at
> scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:37)
> at
> scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:41)
> at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
> at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:600)     at
> scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:570)  at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:219)
> at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.$anonfun$repl$1(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:204)
> at
> scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
> at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:773)
> at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:726)
> at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:204)
> at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$10(DriverLocal.scala:431)
> at
> com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:239)
> at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)   at
> com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:234)
> at
> com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:231)
> at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:48)
> at
> com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:276)
> at
> com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:269)
> at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:48)
> at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:408)
> at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:653)
> at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)     at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:645)
> at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:486)
> at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:598)
> at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:391)
> at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
> at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: working solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64791167/spark-dataframe-from-all-combinations-of-array-column/

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64296594/spark-udf-dont-accept-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your "items" column is of type WrappedArray (which is the Spark type for every array like type). And there is no implicit conversion between Array and WrappedArray. So I would suggest to use Seq because WrappedArray is a subclass of Seq but it is not a subclass of Array.

This works :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}

val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test") 
             .master("local[*]")
             .getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

def func(a: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = a
val funcUDF = udf((a: Seq[Int]) => func(a.toArray))

var data = Seq(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(3, 4, 5), Array(6, 2, 4)).toDF("items")
data = data.withColumn("a", funcUDF(col("items")))
data.show()
```